# Google Maps v3 Geocoding. More than one nearest address

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to backwards geocode Lat/Lng and get the nearest street address.  However this is not always going to be completely accurate.  I need to know if it is possible to get more than just one near street address.

Here is what I have that only gives one full street address result.

```
function locationizer(position){
    latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    longitude = position.coords.longitude;
    latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude,longitude);

    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
      center: latlng,
      zoom: 15
    });

    var request = {
        address: latlng,
        radius: '100',
        types: ['street_address']
      };

      geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if (results[1]) {
          map.setZoom(11);
          console.log(results);

          for(var loc in results){
              $("#output").append(results[loc].formatted_address+"<br />");

        }
      } else {
        alert("Geocoder failed due to: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Example Output

```
100 S High St, New Albany, OH 43054, USA
New Albany, OH, USA
Plain, OH, USA
New Albany, OH 43054, USA
Franklin, OH, USA
Ohio, USA
United States
```